# Pyqt4 accessing objects when creating a dynamic form

Tags: python, oop, object, pyqt4

I have created a layout which adds labels and lineedits automatically, once i assigned it into the list, but for me to create a user I need the values from the line edits and comboxes but as you can see I have set each object names, how could i access all the values in my tryCreateUser() function? as you can see i checked by printing edit but that only gives me the last object!! Thanks for help in advance!

```
def addNewUser(self):
    def tryCreateUser():
        print(edit)

    self.deleteLayout(self.dynamicFrame.layout())

    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    grid.setSpacing(10)
    row = 1
    column = 1
    edit = ['First Name', 1, 'Last Name', 1, 'Date of Birth', 2, '', 'Gender', 3, 'Access Level', 4, 'Password', 5, 'Verify Password', 5]

    for item in edit:
        if item == '':
            self.dob = QtGui.QLabel()
            grid.addWidget(self.dob, 3, 3)
            column -= 1         
        else:
            if item == 1:
                edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            elif item == 2:
                edit = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose')
                edit.clicked.connect(self.openCal)
            elif item == 3:
                edit = QtGui.QComboBox()
                edit.addItem('Male')
                edit.addItem('Female')
            elif item == 4:
                edit = QtGui.QComboBox()
                edit.addItem('General Staff')
                edit.addItem('Stock Admin')
                edit.addItem('Manager')
            elif item == 5:
                edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
                edit.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
            else:
                edit = QtGui.QLabel(item)

        edit.setObjectName(str(item))
        grid.addWidget(edit, row, column)
        if column >= 2:
            column = 1
            row += 1
        else:
            column += 1

    createButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Create User")
    createButton.clicked.connect(tryCreateUser)
    cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
    cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.populateUser)
    grid.addWidget(createButton, row , column)
    grid.addWidget(cancelButton, row, (column+1))

    self.dynamicFrame.setLayout(grid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have each button register itself with a dictionary somewhere. Try this instead:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Button = namedtuple('Button', ["title", "to_do"])

buttons_to_make = [Button("First Name", [1]),
                   Button("Last Name", [1]),
                   Button("Date of Birth", [2, '']),
                   ...]

self.buttons = {}
for button in buttons_to_make:
    for action in button.to_do:
        # your big long if/elif structure here, e.g.:
        if action == 1:
            b = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        elif action == 2:
            b = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose')
            b.clicked.connect(self.openCal)
        # etc
    self.buttons[button.title] = b
```

Then you have a central repository of all your stuff there in `buttons`, and can iterate on that.

```
def tryCreateUser():
    for title, button in self.buttons.items():
        print("Title is {}, button obj is {}".format(title, button))
```

Note that this isn't exactly the way I'd do it, but it IS the closest to your original example. Honestly each of those if blocks should be its own function, such that you'd have something like:

```
def __create_QLineEdit(self):
    b = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    return b

def __create_QPushButton(self):
    b = QtGui.QPushButton("Choose")
    b.clicked.connect(self.openCal)
    self.dob = QtGui.QLabel()
    grid.addWidget(self.dob, 3, 3)
    column -= 1
    return b

...
```

Then you'd define your namedtuple as:

```
Button = namedtuple("Button", ['name','action'])
```

And define `buttons_to_make` as

```
buttons_to_make = [Button("First Name", self.__create_QLineEdit),
                   Button("Last Name", self.__create_QLineEdit),
                   Button("Date of Birth", self.__create_QPushButton),
                   ...]
```

and execute with:

```
buttons = {}
for button in buttons_to_make:
    name, action = button
    buttons[name] = action()
```